# Checking if a user is logged in

Tags: php, security

I'm in the process of trying to make a secure PHP based login system but have come across something I'm unsure how to approach.

After a user is logged in, what is the best method of checking they that they are logged in on subsequent pages?  Currently I'm setting session variables but should I use another method too?  Should I generate a unique ID each time they login, if so how would I use this?  Store a copy in the database & as a cookie and compare them on each page load?  Or any other methods you guys can think of.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Simply storing their userID in session is enough. $_SESSION['uid'] then check if(!empty($_SESSION['uid]) More involved way is to store the entire User object in session, object must be serializable

Comment: @DmitriSnytkine, I could take that session ID, and use it in place of a password on another computer.  It doesn't sound very secure.  Also, cookies should be considered if you want the "Remember Me" functionality, which many sites implement.  (For example, see the [Keep Me Signed In](https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify) on Yahoo.)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand In a shared hosting a good practice is store your sessions (and other sensitive data) in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, and @FakeRainBrigand that bit of information is good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I aways use the session approach, but if you want to be very secure (prevent sessions hijacking) you could save the current IP and some other characteristics of the user in a MD5 hash in the database along with the session ID. Then, when a page is opened after login you can regenerate the MD5 hash with client properties and check that with the session ID in the database. That way it would be much harder, if not impossible, to hijack a session. Of course the 'mysql session' must be deleted, or in any case not reused, because the user might change computers etc, but it would prevent hijacking the active session.

Comment: In theory a solid plan. But I would try to stay away from cookies, if I were browsing your site incognito/anonymous mode, your whole system would fail. If you rely only on the database and information that is always available, there is less that can go wrong.

Comment: Session ID is already a unique id and is stored as cookie on user's computer. Basically php's session is doing exactly what you suggesting, except that it does not store it in the database, but you can write your own session handler class for php that stores sessions in database.

Comment: Not entirely true, because sessions can be hijacked, and as long as the hijacker does not have the cookie on his computer, it would not work. But my previous comment still stands.

Comment: I see your point, my only thought is would it be quite easy for a hacker to find out the users password and spoof it?  Or is it more of a case that someone hijaking the session wouldn't know what the ip address of the actual user was?
Sorry for deleting my previous comment, I was trying to edit it them the time expired and it all went wrong.  For anyone reading this my first comment was to create a unique id and store it in the database and as a cookie.

Comment: Yes the idea is that is is difficult to guess the IP, but not impossible, but combined with several other 'unique features' for the user (user agent etc), its going to be really hard to reproduce. Also, the hacker would have to now how this information is being hashed, and of course you add a salt, so this will be nearly impossible to guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, it's been very helpful.  Think the method I'm settling on is to use the method you described but also have an option in the class that allows it to work with only cookies.
The reason for having that option is that it appears more secure and would be useful in situations that only require a few users to have access to it and it's known they have at least first party cookies enabled.  Correct me if I'm wrong about the security thing though.